# pip install gym-super-mario-bros in this module error is ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

Tags: python, windows, module, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jrei.png)

`your text`
try to run program but error Value Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4) comes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With v0.26 you can use this code

```
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
import gym_super_mario_bros
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT
import gym

env = gym.make('SuperMarioBros-v0', apply_api_compatibility=True, render_mode="human")
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

done = True
env.reset()
for step in range(5000):
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info 
    = env.step(action)
    done = terminated or truncated
    if done:
       state = env.reset()

env.close()
```